# How to swap several objects values?

Tags: javascript

For example I have two objects with same keys:

```
var a = {
    k1: "aa", 
    k2: "ab", 
    k3: "ac", 
    k4: "ad",
    k5: "ae"        
}
var b = {
    k1: "ba", 
    k2: "bb", 
    k3: "bc", 
    k4: "bd",
    k5: "be"        
}
```

For example, I need to swap values k2, k3, k4 between these objects. So, I want to get this result:

```
a = {
    k1: "aa", 
    k2: "bb", 
    k3: "bc", 
    k4: "bd",
    k5: "ae"        
}
b = {
    k1: "ba", 
    k2: "ab", 
    k3: "ac", 
    k4: "ad",
    k5: "be"        
}
```

Is there a way to do this fast? I believe it can be performed without adding intermediate object.

Comment: There are a couple of ways. How do you define which values get swapped? What have you tried? Have you looked into the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` functions:

```js
var a = {k1: "aa",k2: "ab",k3: "ac",k4: "ad",k5: "ae"},
    b = {k1: "ba",k2: "bb",k3: "bc",k4: "bd",k5: "be"},
    swapKeys = ['k2', 'k3', 'k4'];

swapKeys.forEach(function (k) {
    if (k in a && k in b) {
        var values = [a[k], b[k]];
        a[k] = values[1];
        b[k] = values[0];
    }
});

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Nice solution, however this will always loop all the elements in `a`. Since there is regularity in the object's keys you only need to loop the array with key values. However this solution would be more generic.

Comment: @Mouser, indeed, great point, Just missed that. Fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {
    k1: "aa", 
    k2: "ab", 
    k3: "ac", 
    k4: "ad",
    k5: "ae"        
}
var b = {
    k1: "ba", 
    k2: "bb", 
    k3: "bc", 
    k4: "bd",
    k5: "be"        
}

function swap(keys)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  {
     var aOld = a["k"+keys[i]];
     var bOld = b["k"+keys[i]];
     
     a["k"+keys[i]] = bOld;
     b["k"+keys[i]] = aOld;
  }
  
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}

swap([1,3,4]);
```

Well it's all about keys and storage. Since your keys have a certain order. k1 to k5, one can select them fairly easy from the objects `a` and `b`. If you loop the keys and store the values, you can easily swap them as demonstrated.